# Propensity Score Analysis with Ordinal Treatment

Tags: econometrics, ordinal-data, propensity-scores

My treatment variable is more like an ordinal variable, with a range of 0 to 4.

How should I do the analysis in Stata?

Comment: You need to ask better questions in order to get good answers.  My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

1. [Multivalued treatment effects](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/teteffectsmultivalued.pdf)
2. [An ordered-probit inverse probability weighted (IPW) estimator](http://blog.stata.com/2016/09/13/an-ordered-probit-inverse-probability-weighted-ipw-estimator/)

I would recommend the first.

Comment: Impressive how you could compile a good answer to an incomplete question.

Comment: @tomka This question was originally posted as an answer on another question, so I had a bit more context.